# Prototype Chain Always printing Parent method

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
function A(name, gender) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}

A.prototype.speak = function() {
    alert('Calling from A ' + this.name);
};

function B(name, gender){
    this.name = name;
    this.gender = gender;
}

B.prototype.speak = function() {
    alert('Calling from B ' + this.name);
};

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

var b = new B('shane', 'M');
console.log(b);
b.speak();
```

1. Why does the `prototype chain` looks at the parent prototype methods than looking at the Child prototype method?
2. Will my `instance b` only have the `instance propeties` and `methods` and not its `prototype methods`?

The code above prints `"Calling from A Shane"`;

Comment: You are overwriting `B`s prototype with `B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);`

Comment: @NickTomlin: That's fine, but should it still not print speak of B.. as per the Prototype Chain

Comment: it's exactly because of the prototype chain that things aren't working :) The way things are currently written, B's prototype _is_ A's prototype. I've added an answer that hopefully explains things. I've also added a jsbin to demonstrate.

Comment: First set inheritance and then override. You can re use A constructor by calling it in B: A.call(this,name,gender) more on prototype can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because you are setting `B.prototype.speak` first but then you override it by setting the prototype equal to `A.prototype`
2. It will also have its prototype methods

Answer (score 2):

The prototype chain works in the way that expect it to work, but you are overwriting the prototype of B with the prototype of A when you assign it with `Object.create`.

There is nothing magical about prototypical inheritance (confusing, yes, magical, no), it's just traversing up the prototype chain until it finds a matching method. By overwriting B's prototype you've removed B's version of `speak` from the chain.

To have things work out the way you intend (e.g. to have B inherit from A, but have it's own `speak` method), you'll need to overwrite the method from B *after* you've assigned the prototype:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

B.prototype.speak = function() {
    alert('Calling from B ' + this.name);
};
```

**[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jivoyiwidu/1/edit)**

an instance of B will have all the methods on its prototype, but you can additionally add instance only methods if you desire.